# Image Source URIs with HTTPS (SSL) Work, HTTP do NOT Work (React Native v0.30.0)

Tags: image, react-native

In React-Native version 30 certain images are not loading.

this is working

```
<Image style={styles.messageImage} 
       source={{uri:'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}/>
```

This doesn't work

```
<Image style={styles.messageImage} 
       source={{uri:'http://i.imgur.com/lDz3wVn.png'}}/>
```

Looks like images with `https` link are working while those with `http` link are not working. Is anyone else facing this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. open ios/YourProject.xcodeproj in xcode
2. open info.plist as Property List
3. Right click on App Transport Security Settings > Add Row
4. Add `Allow Arbitrary Loads` `Boolean` and set it to `Yes`
5. rebuild your app.

[image]

Xcode by default blocks all the http request and only allows https request. Because it is the right thing to do.

Here is a blog post about App Transport Security: https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Comment: not working for me even after adding this. restarted simulator as well. Internet is working fine in simulator.

Comment: How is this the right thing to do by blocking localhost as well? One thing is Internet, another thing is localhost for development...