# fetch in react-native not working on ios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

I fresh in React-native. I want to fetch data from a server. This is my code :

```
  componentDidMount = ()=> {


        this.handleRequest();

    };


    handleRequest = ()=> {
        fetch("http://********.ir/product/")
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((res)=> {

                console.log(res);
                this.setState({data: res});

            })
            .catch((reason) => {
                console.log(reason);
                this.setState({faildLoad: true});
                AlertIOS.alert(
                    "reason",
                    "Response Body -> " + JSON.stringify(reason)
                )
            })
            .done();
    };
```

and this is error log :

```
{ [TypeError: Network request failed]
  line: 24473,
  column: 21,
  sourceURL: 'http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false' }
```

I dont have any `allow cross origin` problem because im testing this api with ajax in my website. What might be the problem?
I have seen many examples but can't find any difference between them.

Comment: if this is on a device you may require https (secure) instead of http

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587451/image-source-uris-with-https-ssl-work-http-do-not-work-react-native-v0-30-0/38587838?noredirect=1#comment64565216_38587838