# Retrieving Thumbnail using Google Books API in React

Tags: ios, react-native, google-api, google-books

I apologize in advance for the code dump here. I am trying to use the Google Books API to build an iOS app in React Native. However, the thumbnails of the books are not currently showing in the app. One thought of mine that might be causing this is perhaps an http vs. https issue within iOS. I am not positive though (and am not entirely sure how to change that to test it). Can someone please tell me why the thumbnails would not be showing up?

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react'; 
import BookDetail from './BookDetail';

import {
    Image, Text, StyleSheet, View, ListView, ActivityIndicator, TouchableHighlight
   } from 'react-native';

class BookList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           isLoading: true,
           dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
               rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
       })
   };
}

componentDidMount() {
   this.fetchData();
   }

   fetchData() {
       fetch(REQUEST_URL[0])
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseData) => {
           this.setState({
               dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.items),
               isLoading: false
       });
   })
   .done();
     }

render() {
   if (this.state.isLoading) {
       return this.renderLoadingView();
   }

   return (
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderBook.bind(this)}
            style={styles.listView}
            />
    );
}  

renderLoadingView() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.loading}>
            <ActivityIndicator
                size='large'/>
            <Text>
                Loading books...
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}

// **** ISSUE OCCURS HERE (I THINK)

renderBook(book) {
   return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.showBookDetail(book)}  underlayColor='#dddddd'>
            <View>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Image
                        source={{uri: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}} // **NEED TO EDIT THIS
                        style={styles.thumbnail} />
                    <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>{book.volumeInfo.title}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.author}>{book.volumeInfo.authors}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.price}>{'Lowest Available Price: ' + book.volumeInfo.price}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.separator} />
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
   );
}

showBookDetail(book) {
   this.props.navigator.push({
       title: book.volumeInfo.title,
       component: BookDetail,
       passProps: {book}
   });
```

}

```
}

var REQUEST_URL = ['https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=subject:fiction'];

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
       flex: 1,
       flexDirection: 'row',
       justifyContent: 'center',
       alignItems: 'center',
       backgroundColor: '#F1FBFF',
       padding: 10
   },
   separator: {
      height: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#dddddd'
   },
   thumbnail: {
       width: 53,
       height: 81,
       marginRight: 4
   },
   rightContainer: {
       flex: 1
   },
   title: {
       fontSize: 20,
       marginBottom: 4
   },
   author: {
       color: '#656565',
       marginBottom: 4
   }, 
   price: {
       color: '#E41B17'
   }
});


module.exports = BookList;
```

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587451/image-source-uris-with-https-ssl-work-http-do-not-work-react-native-v0-30-0/38587838#38587838

Comment: that worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, Apple will block any unsecure url, use https instead of http.

Try to use this line instead:

source={{uri: 'https'+book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail.substr(4)}}

This will substring the url